# Nodejs app and Vue all in the server file

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have looked for this answer but I could not find anything about it
I am doing maintenance in the Node app which has the front (Vue) as one single application and the server(backend) as another single application.
I do not know how, but when I start the server, in some way, it reads the front project and server the frontend all together with the backend, I mean, I do not need to start the frontend.
So it is like... when I build the server app, it also reads the content of the client folder(frontend app) and merges them into a single app, all into the server app.
How it is possible?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you're asking how the codebase you're working on works, note we can't actually see it.

Comment: You don't need to "start" front-end. You can just create index.html and double click on it and it will open up on your browser. You just serve html file and thats enough

Comment: But why are the changes I do in the frontend does not reflect in the server? What I have to do in order to see the changes I have done when I start the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your front-end is probably configured to serve the `dist` folder on the server, so everything is on the same domain. You probably have a `vue.config.js` file with a property `outputDir` that points to your server directory.

Read this: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/

Comment: You are totally right. There is a vue.config.js  and the output is outside of both projects. I had to copy and paste the generated public folder into the server so I could see the changes I have done in the front. Thanks a lot for your help, I have spent a few days on trying to find the solution.